# NUT UPS Setup Errors

Tags: centos, network-ups-tools

I'm having a strange issue while trying to configure NUT on a CentOS 6 machine to control an Eaton 5E UPS.

I've taken the following steps

```
# yum install nut
# yum install usbutils
```

Then updated nut.conf

```
MODE=standalone
```

I confirmed that the UPS was visible

```
# lsusb

Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0463:ffff MGE UPS Systems UPS
```

Then updated ups.conf

```
[eaton5e]
    driver = usbhid-ups
    port = auto
    desc = "Eaton5E"
    vendorid = 0463
```

Then attempted to run the driver control which failed

```
# upsdrvctl start

Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.6.5
Network UPS Tools - Generic HID driver 0.37 (2.6.5)
USB communication driver 0.31
No matching HID UPS found
Driver failed to start (exit status=1)
```

When I tried to debug it though I got another error and I'm not sure why

```
# usbhid-ups -DDD -a eaton5e

*bunch of stuff*
0.000799     Trying to match device
0.000813     Device matches
0.001630     Unable to get HID descriptor (error sending control message: Broken pipe)
0.001636     HID descriptor, method 2: (9 bytes) => 09 21 10 01 21 01 22 25 02
0.001641     HID descriptor length 549
0.001890     Unable to get Report descriptor: Broken pipe
*more bunch of stuff*
```

I've been fighting this thing for a while now but without any luck, has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Possibly a permission issue on some `/dev/<mumble>`.  Enable debugging and use `strace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by doing the following

1.) copy (or symbolic link) the necessary rules to the correct location

```
# cp /lib/udev/rules.d/62-nut-usbups.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
```

2.) determine correct vendor id for ups

```
# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0463:ffff MGE UPS Systems UPS
```

3.) alter permissions in 62-nut-usbups.rules for correct ups

```
# vim 62-nut-usbups.rules
navigate to correct vendor id and update from
ATTR{idVendor}=="0463", ATTR{idProduct}=="ffff", MODE="664", GROUP="dialout"
to
ATTR{idVendor}=="0463", ATTR{idProduct}=="ffff", MODE="660", GROUP="nut"
```

4.) restart machine